# mysql группировка по категории

Tags: php, mysql, vue.js, php7

есть таблица категории

```
id | title | published
```

и таблица подарков

```
id | title | category_id | published
```

как вывести подарки группируя по категориям во так

```
категория
 --подарок
 --подарок
категория 2
```

пробовал так , но выводит по одному

```
SELECT * FROM `presents` p
left join `category_presents` cp on p.category_present_id = cp.id
where cp.`published` = 1 and p.`published`=1 group by cp.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by в SQL это не такая группировка. Результаты выборки это множество строк, а не дерево. Выбирайте без group by, а дерево формируйте на PHP.

Пример кода

```
select
    `presents`.*,
    `category_presents`.`title` as `category_title`
from `presents`
join `category_presents` on
    `category_presents`.`id` = `presents`.`category_id`
where
    `presents`.`published` = 1
    and `category_presents`.`published` = 1
```

Получите строки:

```
id | title | category_id | published | category_title
```

Теперь в дело идёт php или js (что удобнее для вашей задачи)

```
$presentsByCategory = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ( ! isset($presentsByCategory[$row['category_id']])) {
        $presentsByCategory[$row['category_id']] = (object) [
            'id' => $row['category_id'],
            'title' => $row['category_title'],
            'presents' => [],
        ];
    }

    $presentsByCategory[$row['category_id']]->presents[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: получается этот fоreach формирует дерево? или уже выводит, что-то не пойму

Comment: @Bibika  формирует. Выводить можно по-разному. Это просто пример, как построить такое дерево. Обходите все строки результата из бд, и с одинаковым category_id складываете в группы.